# JQuery / Ajax - get elements from another page except first one

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to load all divs from another page within a main container except the first div.  All divs within the container have class `element`.  The div I don't want has classes `element` AND `first_element`.  What is the best way to achieve this?  Should I utitlize the [not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)?  If so how? Below is what I have so far but this loads in the unwanted first div.

```
$.get(getQuery, null, function(data) {
    container = $('#container', data).eq(0);
    if (container) {
        var newItemsHTML = "";
        newItemsHTML = $(container).html();
        var $newItems = $(newItemsHTML);
        if (loadtype == 'add') {
            $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);
        } else if (loadtype == 'replace') {
            $container.isotope('insert', $newItems, true);
        }
    }
}, 'html');
```

Comment: `var container = $(data).find('#container');
container.find('.element.first_element').remove();` ???  Or: `var container = $(data).find('#container').find('.element.first_element').remove().end();`  BTW, just checking for `first_element` class should be enough

Comment: Ive tried both of your suggestions with no joy :/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake it does work!  If you put this as the answer I'll accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `.first-element` from data, use:

```
var container = $(data).find('#container').find('.first_element').remove().end();
```